# c++ array of interfaces that contains class instances

Tags: c++, memory

How is an array that stores multiple IClass objects, into which we add instances of Class objects that implements IClass gets stored in memory? I am trying to confirm if my assumption is right (in case of 32 bit app)
we have an array of 32 bit pointers to the IClass objects that have a 32 bit pointer to the actual instance object of Class that takes up sizeof(Class) in memory? Also, if an interface doesnt have any virtual/abstract methods it only has a 32 bit pointer at its root and thats it?

Is this right?
as always, any input appreciated

edit:

say we have the following definitons:

```
class Class : IClass
{
   int foo();
   int bar;
}

class IClass
{
   virtual int vfunc();
}

// array def:
IClass arr[1337];
```

I begin storing Class in the array arr, how does the runtime store sizeof(Class) into something that have sizeof(IClass) allocated for it?

Comment: The `IClass` object is a subobject of the derived object. It doesn't necessarily have a pointer to the subobject; if there are virtual methods, it will have a pointer to a vtable which has pointers to the real implementation of each virtual method in the most-derived object.

Comment: cheers for comment. so the array will point to an object of sizeof(Class)?

Comment: An interface only base class, or abstract base class, with no virtual methods isn't much of an interface or abstraction.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is *implementation defined*.

Comment: @geo10 The pointer will be to a subobject of `Class` which means that, while each `Class` object is indeed `sizeof(Class)` bytes long, the `IClass` pointer will almost certainly be offset to point _within_ the `Class` object somewhere (wherever the `IClass` object is stored).

Comment: I have edited my question, can you please see if you have anything in mind with that?

Comment: The array is unable to contain Class objects. [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Comment: @geo10 Polymorphism requires pointers/references. You can't store a `Class` in that array at all. Generally the way you make a list of owned polymorphic objects is `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IClass>>` for example. As an aside, your base type `IClass` should have a virtual destructor if the program is ever going to `delete` an `IClass*`, or there is UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how does the runtime store sizeof(Class) into something that have sizeof(IClass) allocated for it?

It does not. By assigning a `Class` instance to an element of the `IClass` array you are effectively invoking the `IClass` copy-constructor and copying just the parent part of the object. This is called "slicing", [as explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

In order to avoid it, you need to hold *pointers* (or references) to `IClass`. Three problems arise then:

- You cannot copy the actual values, only move them or reference them, unless you implement a virtual "clone" method for your class hierarchy.
- You need to handle ownership: an array of class C owns its instances, but an array of C* or C& does not. Normally you would want to use `unique_ptr<T>` or `shared_ptr<T>`, depending on the lifetime that is expected for the instances and who will see them.
- You need a way to polymorphically construct and destroy the elements. The latter is easy, you just declare the destructor `virtual` at the base class. The former usually involves either somebody else passing you the instances they want saved (e.g. using an `unique_ptr<IClass>` that gives you the ownership) or creating some sort of factory infrastructure.